# Select Box searching?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have already seen jquery Chosen but I want select box where the options are taken from sql table(using php) and can be added by user dynamically. Does anybody know any plugin of this kind

Comment: Take a look at jQuery-UI https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Have a look at [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) with AJAX options and remotes!

Answer (score 3):

[**Select2**](https://select2.github.io) is great. Version 4 just came out and the documentation is very good ( examples etc). Since these are Front end query plugins, it can work against any backend (php, asp.net)